# Proper way to modify messages.php

Tags: magento-1.8, messages

Basically I want to add CSS classes to the Magento core messages.

I want to extend the Mage_Core_Block_Messages class and use the extended class instead of the core one.

How can I do it?

Comment: you have create one small module to ovrride the Mage_Core_Block_Messages class

Comment: Is this not possible without a module? For example to add something to local.xml?

Comment: no local.xml generally used for template design you can do one thing you can copy the core files in local folder but I best way to override the class

Comment: if you want any help then let me know we can discuss on chat

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code for rewriting `Mage_Core_Block_Messages` class 
Code in config.xml

```
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <custom_messages>
                <class>Custom_Messages_Block</class>
            </custom_messages>
            <core>
                <rewrite>
                    <messages>Custom_Messages_Block_Messages</messages>
                </rewrite>
            </core>
        </blocks>
    </global>
```

Code in `Custom_Messages_Block_Messages` class

```
class Custom_Messages_Block_Messages extends Mage_Core_Block_Messages {     public function getGroupedHtml()
    {
        $types = array(
            Mage_Core_Model_Message::ERROR,
            Mage_Core_Model_Message::WARNING,
            Mage_Core_Model_Message::NOTICE,
            Mage_Core_Model_Message::SUCCESS
        );
        $html = '';
        foreach ($types as $type) {
            if ( $messages = $this->getMessages($type) ) {
                if ( !$html ) {
                    $html .= '<' . $this->_messagesFirstLevelTagName . ' class="customClass messages">'; //Custom css class added
                }
                $html .= '<' . $this->_messagesSecondLevelTagName . ' class="' . $type . '-msg anotherCustomClass">'; // Custom css class added
                $html .= '<' . $this->_messagesFirstLevelTagName . '>';

                foreach ( $messages as $message ) {
                    $html.= '<' . $this->_messagesSecondLevelTagName . '>';
                    $html.= '<' . $this->_messagesContentWrapperTagName . '>';
                    $html.= ($this->_escapeMessageFlag) ? $this->htmlEscape($message->getText()) : $message->getText();
                    $html.= '</' . $this->_messagesContentWrapperTagName . '>';
                    $html.= '</' . $this->_messagesSecondLevelTagName . '>';
                }
                $html .= '</' . $this->_messagesFirstLevelTagName . '>';
                $html .= '</' . $this->_messagesSecondLevelTagName . '>';
            }
        }
        if ( $html) {
            $html .= '</' . $this->_messagesFirstLevelTagName . '>';
        }
        return $html;
    } }
```

But I would suggest if you just want to add css styles in to message blocks, then you can do so by using current classes only.

Comment: You mean that I should modify the config.xml?

Comment: Above code is while you are rewriting core classes in your custom module. We never do modifications in core files directly, we always override them.

Comment: But is this possible without creating a custom module? 
For example to add a phtml file into the template, and to add some code into local.xml?

Comment: No, in local.xml we do changes related to our layout and here we are not changing anything in layout. we are adding classes to template and template get formed in block class Mage_Core_Block_Messages

Comment: I have added the php code you provided in app/code/local/DM/CustomMessages/Block/Messages.php . What am I missing?

Comment: check if this class is not already been overridden by some other class.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem with extension of Mage_Core_Block_Messages was the compilation of magento: System->Tools->Compilation

The system simple did not load the php file, and was giving white screen of death